# android p2p connection

Tags: java, android, xmpp, p2p

i'm developing an android game that will need p2p communication.

I really searched a lot about this topic but all the solutions does not seem to fit my needs or i didn't find enough documentation to make them work.

I tried the raw way, looking for some STUN solution and found a way to learn the public ip of an android (or any) phone, but didn't found out how to use this information to communicate with it (e.g. on what port to post the request).

I tried the (almost) pretty way of using an IM solution, so that 2 clients would communicate like we do in chats. I choosed the XMPP protocol for some reasons, and found a lot of libraries for creating any kind of client. But i also need a solution for the server. I don't want to use gtalk accounts and i don't want to use a real hosting solution. I'm thinking of publishing a light weight server on google appspot, but only to help the p2p connections.

Questions...

1) hints about how to use STUN

2) how can i embed a XMPP server in java? (i'm trying to use the JSO library but with no luck at the moment)

3) is there some "prepackaged" solution in google apis?

Thank you in advance

Answer (score -1):

Check this
http://developer.android.com/google/gcm/ccs.html
You can use the android client to communicate with a simple java servlet that uses the google cloud API and send messages/chats to the other android client

Comment: The GCM could not be used for this because it only let you send data from an app server to Android devices. It does not let you send messages between devices.